# Bootstrap responsive images and fix sized thumbnails

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to bootstrap so please forgive me if my question is trivial. I have a page that is displaying rows of images (4x4). However, the images are of different sizes. What I want to do is display the images as thumbnails (fixed sizes: height = 200px, width 300px) but I still want to maintain the responsiveness of my page. So, when the screen size changes, it uses bootstrap responsive css. I tried setting the fixed width and height in `img-thumbnail` but I loose the responsiveness. Any suggestions? By the way, I am using Asp.net MVC, if anyone wants to know.

**Bootstrap**

```
.img-responsive,
.thumbnail > img,
.thumbnail a > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.img-rounded {
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.img-thumbnail {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 4px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
          transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

**My Index Page**

```
<img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" src="@Model.ItemPaged.ElementAt(x).src" alt="">

</div>
```

Comment: Spend some time on bootsnipp.com and you'll find snippets related to your request.. I am on mobile app and can't help much at the moment.

Comment: @RajshekarReddy okay thank you.

Comment: I got hold of my machine.. here are some snippets that might interest you, its all built using bootstrap.. So it must be a good fit for you. http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/E7Kp6 , http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/E7op8 , http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/2nvg2 , 
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/4pv3 , 
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/jba9q

Answer (score 0):

you can set the max-width of that image 300px and width 100%. So that it will take the maximum width 300px when it will be available(on web) and on responsive it will take the full width of its container.
    img{
        max-width: 300px;
        width: 100%;
    }